# R shiny datatable pagination and show all rows as options

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I have a datatable in a shiny application where I am doing pagination to show only 15 rows. But can I add an option where the user can see 15 rows at a time using pagination or a show all button which will show all the records with a scroll bar may be.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)


shinyApp(

  ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'DataTable',
    tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('ex2'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(
        iris, options = list(
          lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
          pageLength = 15
        )
      )
    )

    }
    )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this, using the buttons extension.  We define a custom button that calls the javascript function `page.len(-1)`, where `-1` means all rows:

```
shinyApp(

  ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'DataTable',
    tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('ex2'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(
        iris, 
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        options = list(
          dom = 'Bfrtip',
          lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
          pageLength = 15,
          buttons = list(
            list(
              extend = "collection",
              text = 'Show All',
              action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                    dt.page.len(-1);
                                    dt.ajax.reload();
                                }")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )

  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can there be another button next to it which would reset to `pagelength = 15` ? And have the show all button near the pagination buttons.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: Just another small question. When expanded can it increase the table size without scroll

Comment: I don't really follow that comment.  Can you explain question more clearly? And if its non-trivial, its probably better to ask a new question than have a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `dom = "ft"` in the options of `renderDataTable`. [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) are all the dom options. Basically this is only enabling "f - filtering" and "t - table". The "p-pagination" is missing. Then set the `pageLength` to be displayed to something really big (`10000` rows in this example)*. Below is minimal example based on your code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('my_table')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, 
    options = list(dom = "ft",
                   pageLength = 10000)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

*Better yet, make the `pageLength` dynamic based on the size of your table.

Comment: This is the simplest way to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(

  ui = navbarPage(
    title = 'DataTable',
    tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('ex2'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(
        iris, 
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        options = list(
          dom = 'tpB',
          lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
          pageLength = 15,
          buttons = list(
            list(
              extend = "collection",
              text = 'Show All',
              action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(-1);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}")
            ),list(
              extend = "collection",
              text = 'Show Less',
              action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                              dt.page.len(10);
                              dt.ajax.reload();}")

              )
              )
              )
            )
          )

  }
      )
```